# Android application that downloads images from bing image search not having the correct image

Tags: android, image, jsoup, bing

I have an android application that has a button and an image view
when clicking the button the application goes to bing image search and search for images then get the url of the first image and make it the source of the image view so that it has the first image of the search
When I do the image search using the explorer (I use chrome) I find that the first image displayed in my browser is not the same displayed in the image view
when I search for (facebook.com logo) or (google.com logo) the image view is the same of the first image shown in the search result but if I change the search to (yahoo.com logo) the image view is the second
If I change the search to (outlook.com logo) it takes the 10th image of the search and if I search for (hotmail.com logo) it does not show an image related to hotmail at all
I use JSOUP library to parse the HTML of the web page of the search results
here is the xml of the project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="arb.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="131dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:elevation="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the Java file of the project:

```
   package arb.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attribute;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    class DownloadIcon extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Integer>
    {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Object... objects) {
            Connection connecion= Jsoup.connect("http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=outlook.com+logo");
            try {
                Document document=connecion.get();
                Elements element=document.select("img.mimg");
                String url=element.get(0).absUrl("src");
                    InputStream inputStream= new URL(url).openStream();
                    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                publishProgress(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                publishProgress(-1);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap) values[0];
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloadIcon().execute();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Help me please

Comment: Are you comparing to a mobile browser or desktop browser? If desktop: try setting a non-mobile userAgent.

Comment: I am comparing to a desktop browser
Please help me setting the non-mobile user Agent @FredericKlein

Comment: `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36").get();` result for mobile user agent string and desktop differ, but I still see different results comparing with desktop browser, might be cookie related.

Comment: Thanks @FredericKlein

Comment: Did the userAgent fix your issue?

Comment: not really
I am still getting different results although I looked using the internet for the user agent of my desktop browser @FredericKlein